# Modern algebra and set theory: ZFC vs. NBG

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, set-theory, foundations

This may be somewhat of a philosophical question and is probably nitpicking, but it is also one that has always bothered me a little:

Is it not more natural consider NBG set theory as the foundation for modern algebra as opposed to traditional ZFC? To me, ZF has always seemed sort of hacky, for lack of a better word, as if it has been patched and patched over the years; kind of how windows vista would look today if it were still in use. It is no doubt an extremely powerful theory, but the point is that in modern application ZF tends to be somewhat inadequate, seemingly always requiring a work around; thus, hacky. On the other hand, NBG deals with classes directly, and is just for all intents and purposes more accessible from the algebraic viewpoint, especially from the point of view of lattice and order theory, all the way to class field theory. NBG is just better equipped for the job.

I guess an easier way to say all of this is that while ZF is more concerned with objects, NBG is designed to exploit the relationships between objects, which, in my opinion is more fundamental to not only mathematics, but to logic itself. NBG is implemented naturally to exhibit the abilities of comparison and deduction, which can be argued to form the basis for the concept of logic, in and of itself.

Am I crazy, or has anyone else ever felt this way?

Comment: You should switch to linux and [SEAR](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SEAR#introduction).

Comment: @k.stm: How is that Linux? If anything, that's DEC10.

Comment: Lol, I do use Linux, it was just an analogy.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Funnily, the page I linked to even indulges in that metaphor itself (which I didn’t know before): “Or, using an alternate metaphor, ZFC is like Windows, ETCS is like UNIX, and SEAR is like OS X (or maybe Ubuntu).” And maybe it’s not Ubuntu, but Debian or Arch or something.

Comment: @k.stm: As someone who's been doing set theory for a while now, and been working with Linux for a while longer, and with Windows even longer than that, the comparison is bad. The comparison should be between CPU architectures, not operating systems.

Comment: @k.stm That is pretty ironic. But I just glossed over the page, and it seems like basically an informal NBG, using the notion of relations instead of formally defining proper classes

Comment: @AsafKaragila I trust you on this – I don’t know much set theory (meaning I almost don’t know any at all). Do you agree with the rest of the comparison or do you maybe know any other informal comparison of SEAR/ZFC or structural/material set theory that you find good? I’m (shallowly) interested in this.

Comment: @k.stm: Not quite. The reason that ZFC is "Windows" or that "you hop in the car and go" is that for many years people worked on allowing mathematicians to do just that. It wasn't always like that. Informally, structural and material set theories are two different costumes of the same wolf. They just differ in approach as to what is primitive and how to say things. I can't say much more, since I don't know too much about structural set theory. I just know enough to say I prefer $\sf ZFC$. :-)

Comment: As an algebraist, I feel like this is only an issue when writing foundations. At other times, the set theory one uses is almost always out of the way.

Comment: @Asaf: Besides, $\mathsf{NBG}$ is self-evidently No Bloody Good! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many people have felt like that.

This is why you often hear people in algebra moaning about set theory, or ignoring set theoretic issues (they usually can point out where these issues arise, and that someone out there knows how to solve them). This is also why there are people who are very enthusiastic about algebraic set theories like $\sf ETCS$, or type theories like $\sf SEAR$ and $\sf HTT$, which may or may not prove to be a better foundation for algebra.

But switching from $\sf ZFC$ to $\sf NBG$ only pushes the problem "one step further". Sure, now you have the class of all groups as an actual object. But what about the category of all small categories? That's not a class anymore, since only sets are allowed to be elements of other classes, and small categories are not necessarily classes.

This is why working with universes is easier here. They allow you to jump "one level up" without any consequences. Each time you just extend the definition of what it means to be a set, and include more things as sets.

Comment: I see your point, however, I was under the impression that NBG could handle such discussion. Is a universe not a class?

Comment: Actually, I guess since we are talking about the categories of all categories, we would simply allow for impredicative comprehension, right?

Comment: The universe is a class. But classes are not objects of other classes. So a category whose objects are small categories is a collection whose objects are themselves classes, and for this collection to be "in the universe" you need to either allow 2-classes (thus extend again), or that all the categories you worked with were actually sets to begin with. What NBG gives you is the ability to quantify over proper classes, which makes dealing with small categories (and to a very very minor degree, for making statements about arbitrary small categories) much easier.

Comment: Altenatively, couldn't we simply a priori give a formal definition of say the "logical scope" of a variable in a logical formula and allow for modification to a particular subject matter, thus making any logical formula "scope-dependent". I.e. we could stop defining scope-independent variables, so that when we choose to generalize, paradoxical "spillover" of quantified variables are in some sense modded out by restriction to the new scope.

Comment: That sounds dangerously close to type theory. :-)

Comment: I figured you would catch that ;)